# Dockerfile mongo: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I have Dockerfile

```
FROM mongo
RUN mkdir -p /app/data
WORKDIR /app/data
COPY cars.csv /app/data
RUN mongod --fork --syslog
CMD ["mongoimport", "-d", "Gene", "-c", "Genes", "--type", "csv", "--file", "cars.csv", "--headerline"]
EXPOSE 27017:27017
```

I build and start the docker file using the following commands

> `docker build -t "mtest:1" .`

> `docker run mtest:1`

the run command gives me the following error

```
2022-01-07T19:01:12.784+000 error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: 
server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: localhost:27017, 
Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: 
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: connect: connection refused }, ] }
```

the output of docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                          PORTS     NAMES
e623f431b9db   mtest:1   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago    Exited (1) About a minute ago             cranky_satoshi
```

When I try to do inside the container using `docker exec -it e623f431b9db bash` and run `mongod` I get the following

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I'm new to this and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overwritten the mongo startup procedure with your own `CMD`, such that the Mongo server doesn't start anymore. Therefore, `mongoimport` will fail, and your container will exit.

Instead, just run the original Mongo image by itself with a volume mount, then exec into it, and run your import function. Afterwards, it'll still be running, and you can connect to it.

By the way, `EXPOSE 27107:27107` isn't a valid expression.

Comment: I tired it worked. But is there not any solution in which I can wait for Mongo to start then run mongoimport in my docker file

Comment: i even tried `RUN mongod --fork --syslog`

Comment: There is no workaround, since you would end up forking a process for the `mongoimport`, and overriding PID 1, causing the docker daemon to reap the process and cause a zombie process in the container.

Comment: What if I somehow wait for the parent process till the child exits?

Comment: The fact that you "wait" for one process requires running a different process that's not PID 1. https://petermalmgren.com/signal-handling-docker/